# Downloading .ics file and accessing data through Calendar

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, icalendar

I am creating a Mobile Application *(Windows Phone)* using C# and I am working with Calendar data, that, currently is stored as a `.ics` in which can be downloaded and then imported to your calendar.

I am looking for a way where I can download the `.ics` file and import it to the calendar that is on the phone and then use the data `(Month/Week/Day/Location/Time/Event)` inside my application based upon the current time.

For example:

> Person A has a meeting at 9am on Jan 13th 2012 at 13:00 and the data
>   is stored on a server that can be downloaded as a .ics file, in which
>   can be imported onto the phone calendar and then have an application
>   access this data so he can be prompted (through the app) when the
>   appointment is.

Is this possible in the language and platform I am using? If so, could anyone recommend any tutorials on how I would achieve this.